# Programming a Baby Orangutan using Arduino Uno?

Tags: arduino, avr, programming, programmer, pololu

I have the following setup:
[Arduino UNO](http://www.arduino.cc/en/Main/arduinoBoardUno) without the chip:
[image: Arduino UNO]
*Notice that the Atmel chip is missing.*

And i have a [Baby Orangutan](http://www.pololu.com/catalog/product/1220/resources):
[image: Orangutan]

**The orangutan burned with Arduino Uno R3 Bootloader.**

I connected Orangutans **PD0** (RX) and **PD1** (TX) to the Uno's **D0** (RX) and **D1** (TX) so that i can program the orangutan using **Arduino AVR programmer**.

When I'm connecting my Uno to the PC using a USB Cable, it's being recognized as a Uno R3 even when the chip is off, becuase the Orangutan has a Uno bootloader.

Now the problem is when I'm trying to upload a sketch it sais:

```
avrdude: stk500_getsync(): not in sync: resp=0x00
```

### UPDATE:

The following pins are connected:

```
> Uno      -->   Orangutan  
> D1 (TX)  -->   PD1 (TX)  
> D0 (RX)  -->   PD0 (RX)  
> 5V       -->   VIN  
> GND      -->   GND  
> RST      -->   PC6 (RST)
```

Following: [Baby Orangutan B Pin Mappings](http://www.pololu.com/docs/0J17/2.b).

Comment: The PC's identification of the board is based on the USB serial chip, not on the bootloader. So you have not yet proven connectivity to the bootloader.  This is likely either a mistmatch between the bootloader's baud rate and that set in the arduino GUI, or else a problem resetting the target, or else TX/RX interchanged.

Answer (score 4):

From your description and the first photograph, your Uno and Orangutan do not have their Ground lines connected. This could be an oversight in your description, but if not, two circuits need to have a common reference for this kind of programming link to work. **Wire the GND pins of the two boards together** if you haven't already.

To program boards similar to the Baby Orangutan, here are the connections I use from my Uno with the MCU removed:

```
> Uno    -->   Other  
> TX     -->   TX  (*note)  
> RX     -->   RX  (*note)  
> 5V     -->   Vcc  
> GND    -->   GND  
> RST    -->   RST
```

**note*: On at least one board, the TX and RX lines needed to be reversed.

Comment: I connected my Orangutan the the Uno's **5V** and **GND**, so now it has common ground lines (fix me if I'm worng), connected arduino **RST** to Orangutan **RST**, and by reversed **TX RX** you mean:
`TX -> RX, RX -> TX`  ?
I tried both configurations but still not in sync while uploading..

Comment: @Danpe Yes, reversing TX/RX means precisely that. Now, if that too didn't work, you may have to fiddle with the reset line on the Uno. There are discussions on arduino.cc about wiring a capacitor (various opinions on how many microfarads) between the RST pin and GND, another group suggests a resistor between RST and Vcc. It would behoove you to look up those discussions, it'll be trial and error, a bit.

Comment: Another experiment worth trying is to hit the board's reset button (if it has one) *just after* you click on the Arduino UI to upload a sketch. If not, try pressing the Uno's reset button instead.